# Not Seeing All The Post Objects?

Tags: json, wordpress, reactjs, react-native, wordpress-rest-api

The code below pulls from a JSON object, however there's one major problem with it:

It's seeing 10 posts out of 98. I should see all 98 shouldn't I ? Since I'm using a flatlist it should pull all the available posts, but it stops at 10. However, if I console.log, I see about 30 posts, but still not all 98.

```
              render() {
              return (
                <View style={styles.theContainer}>
                  <FlatList
                  data={this.state.data}
                  keyExtractor={(x,i)=>i}
                  renderItem={({item}) => {
                    return (
                      <View>
                        <HTMLView
                          value={item.title.rendered}
                          styles={styles.topicTitle}
                        />
                        <HTMLView
                          value={item.excerpt.rendered}
                        />
                      </View>
                    )}
                  }
                  />
                </View>
              );
              }
            }
```

Comment: I can properly run your code and see all the items but I have to say with my own api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override some properties in your flatlist. As a start, set the initialNumToRender property equal to the initial number of records you want to show.

Also, the API requires you to specify how many records you want like this:

```
/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100
```

See the docs here!

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

From the docs:

"The API endpoints default to providing a limited number of items per request, the same way that a WordPress site will default to 10 posts per page in archive views."